# Redis publish function time

Tags: redis

Think I have 100,000 user and each user subscribe to they own channel , so each client have one channel .

from redis documention , I saw this for publish functon :

*Time complexity: O(N+M) where N is the number of clients subscribed to the receiving channel and M is the total number of subscribed patterns (by any client).*

Now a user publish an message to only one another user ...

What is N And M in my example ?

Answer (score 0):

- N = 1 because each client listens to its own channel
- M = 0 because you didn't mention pattern subscriptions ([PSUBSCRIBE](http://redis.io/commands/psubscribe))

Comment: So , if I use that as notification center , even I get 100,000,000 user , they notification send instantly , yes ?

Comment: If redis will be able to hold that number of connections, yes.

Comment: Thanks , I think you are expert in redis , Also a small question , do you think redis for node or standalone support of multi server , can redis share key-values between many server , something what mysql cluster do ...

Comment: No. If you need several Redis instances, you need to shard your data, and distribute the connections over the instances. Redis Cluster is not ready yet for prime time.